# java web application authenticate with adfs 2.0

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am new to Java and i developing a small web application using spring web, using java config. Now i want my clients to authenticate using ADFS 2.0, i tried the spring security SAML sample app but i couldn't run it (i got this error: http://s14.postimg.org/tzlzaumrl/IMG_20160321_174454_resized.jpg).

so I started look for another way to implement saml in my app but i don't know what is the best and simplest way to do so.

In .Net it's very simple, you just right click on the project, enter the app URL and the ADFS metadata URL and thats all. is there any easy way in java to do that?

Answer (score 0):

"is there any easy way in java to do that" - No.

Your error is an invalid response. Look in the ADFS event log for clues.

You need to use a SAML stack - refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).